# Qt - remove menu from bottom?

Tags: c++, qt, mobile, qt4

How in the world do I get rid of these buttons?[image]

Comment: Might want to tag this with mobile tag.

Comment: What widget class are you using?

Comment: Do they not appear in the object hierarchy panel? If they do then you can just right click -> delete/remove

Comment: You have to sacrifice a RED goat, not a yellow one.

Comment: QStackedWidget, with QTabWidget as main layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `showFullScreen()` on your `QMainWindow`.